# Display 404 page when trying to view a profile for a nonexistent user

Tags: php, .htaccess

In my site users profiles have urls mysite.com/user/username. What I actually want to do that urls should be mysite.com/username.
And I have done it adding these lines of code to htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?uname=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?uname=$1
```

now i can reach users from mysite.com/username. but error is, now 404 document is not working. if i type url that does not exist like myste.com/dasdfsf, it does not get 404 document because it is looking on all numbers and letters(to find a username) and gives me 
a blank page which i have created for invalid usernames. I want it to show a 404 page if that user does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why show a blank page for invalid usernames?  Show your 404 page instead.

Comment: Yep: `if ( ! $user_exists) header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found'); include 'error_404.php';`

Answer (score 2):

The redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?uname=$1 [L] #use the L option to stop processing
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?uname=$1 [L]
```

To show a 404 you will need to set up a 404 page and add logic to your `user.php` to read it.

```
<?php
    if(!userExist()){
        header('Status: 404 Not Found');
        echo file_get_contents('404.php');
        exit;//do this if there is code below that assumes this is a valid user
    }
?>
```

Comment: I would avoid the redirect, sending a 404 header *and* 302, plus making the user lose the location in the address bar, is problematic and bad UX.

Comment: Actually! This sends a 404 status and sets the Location HTTP header. Crawlers will get the 404 status they want and the browser most likely follow the Location header. But, as you said this isn't ideal which is why I gave him 2 solutions. The 404 and echo the 404 page or 404 and send the location of the 404 page.

Comment: I hear people asking how to do a "404 redirect" fairly often and just really try to discourage it. Why would you *want* to redirect when you can simply load the content from the page you intended to redirect to?

Comment: I don't use the redirect myself. I just like to give people options. But, to help you out on your quest to eradicate it, I will edit my answer. :)

Comment: header('Location: 'oops.html'); worked for me. but it redirects and not get contents